# Number of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ such that every number is less than or equal to the average of its $2$ neighbours (if any).

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

Question:

> Find the number of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ such that every number is less than or equal to the average of its $2$ neighbours (if any).

My attempt:

I immediately noticed that $n$ must be at the $2$ ends. This encourages us to use recursion since every time $n$ increases, it is just added to either of the $2$ ends.

Let the number of such permutations be $x_n$. Suppose that a possible sequence is $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n\}$ and we want to insert $n+1$. As I've said above, either $a_1$ is $n$ or $a_n$ is $n$. Here's where I got stuck. Suppose that $a_1$ is $n$. Then, we do not know whether letting $a_0=n+1$ (i.e. inserting $n+1$ in front) works, because we have to ensure that $a_1=n$ is less than or equal to the average of $a_0$ and $a_2$, and we cannot ensure this, so I got stuck.

I have no other methods except to brute-force everything. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $n$ large enough, the number of such permutations is $8$. For instance, if $n = 10$, the only permutations are: 
```[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10],
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10],
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
[10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9],
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]```
Do you see additional patterns?

Comment: How do you rigorously prove that it is $8$ tho?

Comment: You miss many answers, example [10,5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]

Comment: @Lourrran Are you sure? In your example, $6$ is larger than the average of $4$ and $7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of this as a structure-finder/avoider problem.

We use the shorthand $[i:j]$ to reference to the subsequence from $a_i, a_{i+1}, \ldots, a_j$.

The crux is the following observations:

1. In $[i:j]$, the largest element in that sequence must be at either end -> OP made this observation for the entire sequence, that $n$ has to be at the end.
2. In $[i:j]$, if the end with the largest element has an adjacent element that is one less, then the rest of the sequence is uniquely determined of the form $\{k, k-1, k-2, k-3 \ldots,k-j+i \}$.

Now, apply these observations repeatedly.

- (O1) $n$ is at either end, WLOG $a_n = n$.
- (O1)  Ignoring $n$ for now, $n-1$ is either end, so $a_1$ or $a_{n-1}$.

  - (O2) If $ a_{n-1} = n-1$, since $a_n=n$ so the entire sequence $[1:n]$ is uniquely determined. This is Jeroen's $T1$.
  - Henceforth $a_1 = n-1$.
- (O1) Ignoring $n, n-1$ for now, $n-2$ is at either end, so $a_2 $ or $a_{n-1}$.

  - (O2) If $a_2 = n-2$, since $a_1 = n-1$ so the entire sequence $[1:n-1]$ is uniquely determined, and hence so is $[1:n]$. This is Jeroen's $T4$.
  - Henceforth $a_{n-1} = n-2$.
- (O1) Ignoring $n, n-1, n-2$ for now, $n-3$ is at either end, so $a_{n-2}$ or $a_2$.

  - (O2) If $a_{n-2} = n-3$, then $[2:n-1]$ is uniquely determined. This is Jeroen's $T2$.
  - (Observation 3) If $a_2 = n-3$, then the sequence is uniquely determined and each value (other than $a_j = 1$) will be $\pm 2$ of its neighbors. This is Jeroen's $T3$.

Thus, there are $ 2 \times (1+1+1+1) = 8 $ solutions when $ n-3 \geq 1$.
The cases of $ n \leq 3$ is left to the reader.

Answer (score 4):

A not-so-satisfying approach to rigorously prove that the answer is $8$ for large enough $n$ is to simply catalogue the list of solutions, and prove inductively that these are the only ones. The induction step proceeds using your observations that the number $n$ always appears at the start or the end, so to get a suitable permutation of $1,\ldots,N+1$, you need to append the number $N+1$ to either the start or end of a suitable permutation of $1,\ldots,N$.

For $n = N$, the $8$ solutions admit the following patterns.

- $T_1$: $\{1, 2 \ldots, N-1, N\}$
- $T_2$: $\{N-1, 1, 2, \ldots, N-2, N\}$
- $T_3$: $\{N-1, N-3, \ldots, 1,\ldots,N-2,N\}$
- $T_4$: $\{N-1, N-2, \ldots, 2, 1, N\}$
- $T_5$: Reverse of type 4
- $T_6$: Reverse of type 3
- $T_7$: Reverse of type 2
- $T_8$: Reverse of type 1

An example for $N = 10$ is illustrated in my initial comment to your question. Now let $s$ be the act of adding $N+1$ to the start of a sequence, and $e$ the act of adding $N+1$ to the end of a sequence. Then

You can now attach the number $N+1$ in precisely $8$ possible ways:

- $s(T_1) = T_5$
- $e(T_1) = T_1$
- $s(T_3) = T_6$
- $s(T_4) = T_7$
- $e(T_5) = T_2$
- $e(T_6) = T_3$
- $s(T_8) = T_8$
- $e(T_8) = T_4$

Still hoping someone else comes up with a cleverer solution.